# How to reduce grpc static libraries (C++ version) file size on Windows?

Tags: c++, windows, grpc

I'm trying to involve gRpc to our company's product, the gRpc is 1.52.x, C++ windows version. I follow the instructions on https://github.com/grpc/grpc/blob/master/BUILDING.md, but after compiling, I found the release binaries are too big, grpc.lib is about 70MB, but our product is only 8MB. I think it's not acceptable to include such big static library to our product. Is there any methods to reduce the static libraries' size?

You can refer the screenshot in this question.
[image]

Thanks a lot!

---

Thanks for all your comments, I would like to describe more details about my issue. Here are my steps to reproduce the issue:

1. clone the grpc source code from git hub and checkout v1.52.x branch
2. run git command

   `git submodule update --init`
3. Create VS 2017 project through command

   `cmake .. -G "Visual Studio 15 2017 Win64"`
4. open the grpc solution and choose release version, then start building.

Per my current investigation, the file size depends on the grpc versions.

v1.52.x - release - grpc.lib - about 70MB

v1.51.x - release - grpc.lib - about 50MB

v1.33.x - release - grpc.lib - about 23MB

I also tried to turn on all optimization options in grpc solution, for example, use Favor Size. The file size can also be decreased.

But still could not understand why the static library so big, this exceeds my understanding of a static library.

Comment: Are users expected to compile your product or are you shipping a precompiled version?

Comment: I would like to provide a precompiled static library to them. At first, I want to download a precompiled library from gRpc official site, but found there is only source code.

Comment: What compilation options have you used? Also, CMake or Bazel?

Comment: I just follow the instruction in BUILDING.MD. I use CMake command `cmake .. -G "Visual Studio 14 2015"` and `cmake --build . --config Release`. I also tried to disable some option, such as "-DgRPC_BUILD_GRPC_CPP_PLUGIN=OFF -DgRPC_BUILD_GRPC_CSHARP_PLUGIN=OFF -DgRPC_BUILD_GRPC_NODE_PLUGIN=OFF", but got a lot of errors

Comment: The reason I ask is that the static library would normally be compiled into your application and the users of that application would not need it, the code is in the app. Are you providing the library so they can use it to compile your application and link with it?

Comment: I want to link the static library to our product. But this grpc static library is so big, and we only use part of its functionalities, if link the static library, our product size will be increased to more than 100MB, which will confuse our customers.

Comment: How did you perform a build? I've checked my project (also using grpc linked statically). Turns out that debug builds on my machine have similar sizes and release builds of it are 10 times smaller or more.

Comment: If you link the library to your product, then there is no need to deliver the library with your product. If you complain about the EXE file size, it's a new question.

Comment: Can you doublecheck that you aren't accidentally including symbols in the .lib libraries? (with "Release" config they should be stripped).  Also, aren't you compiling the zlib-compatible mode with /Z7 option?  This option prevents creation of a separate .pdb file with symbols, but rather adds the symbols to the .lib files (which can result in larger than usual size of the .lib files) See https://github.com/grpc/grpc/blob/master/cmake/ccache.cmake